resolved promise stops rendering of Vue components
I use getCardsById in KanbanBoardGroup.vue to return a Promise<Card[]> but if i dont resolve it the v-for in DraggableContent wont know its a Card[]
<DraggableContent v-for="card in cardGroup" :key="card.id" :data="card">

and when hover over id in :key="card.id" it tells me this

Property 'id' does not exist on type 'string | (<TResult1 = Card[], TResult2 = never>(onfulfilled?: ((value: Card[]) => TResult1 | PromiseLike) | null | undefined, onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<...>) | null | undefined) => Promise<...>) | (<TResult = never>(onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult | PromiseLike<...>) | .....'.
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'string'.

As result of this DraggableContent wont render the Cards i get with getCardsById.
But if i resolve the promise then KanbanBoardGroup component wong get rendered in the KanbanBoard component. What is going on?
How can i resolve the promise and get an array of Card type and then use v-for to render Draggable compenents with values from the Card
let cardGroup = await getCardsById(props.id)

File: KanbanBoardGroup.vue


<template>
  <section class="flex-1 list-none drop-zone">
    <div v-if="cardGroup">
      <DraggableContent v-for="card in cardGroup" :key="card.id" :data="card">
        {{ card }}
      </DraggableContent>
      <p>lol</p>
      <CreateCard :groupId="props.id"></CreateCard>
    </div>
    <div v-else>Loading cards...</div>
  </section>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, defineProps, defineEmits, computed } from 'vue'
import axios from 'axios'
import CreateCard from './CreateCard.vue'
import DraggableContent from './DraggableContent.vue'

const props = defineProps({
  id: Number,
  title: String
})
interface Card {
  id: number
  title: string
  description: string
  groupId: number
}

const get = async <T,>(url: string): Promise<T> => {
  try {
    const response = await axiosInstance.get<T>(url)
    return response.data
  } catch (error: any) {
    throw new Error(`Failed to fetch data from ${url}. ${error.message}`)
  }
}

const getCardsById = async (groupId: any): Promise<Card[]> => {
  try {
    const data = await get<Card[]>(`cards/${groupId}`)
    return data.map((card) => ({
      id: card.id,
      title: card.title,
      description: card.description,
      groupId: card.groupId
    }))
  } catch (err: any) {
    throw new Error(err.message)
  }
}

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000'
})

//I resolve Card[] 

let cardGroup = await getCardsById(props.id)
console.log(cardGroup)
</script>



File: KanbanBoard

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import KanbanBoardGroup from './KanbanBoardGroup.vue'
import CreateKanbanGroup from './CreateKanbanGroup.vue'
import useKanbanGroups from '@/composeables/useKanbanGroups'
import { onMounted } from 'vue'
import type { KanbanGroup } from '@/types/KanbanGroupTypes'

const kanbanData = ref<any[]>([])

onMounted(async () => {
  const { getKanbanGroups } = useKanbanGroups()
  const data = await getKanbanGroups()
  kanbanData.value = data
  console.log(kanbanData.value, 'DATA')
  console.log(data, 'DATA here')
})

const handleNewGroup = async (group: KanbanGroup) => {
  kanbanData.value.push(group)
  console.log(kanbanData.value)
}

const handleDeleteGroup = async (groupId: KanbanGroup) => {
  const index = kanbanData.value.findIndex((group) => group.id === groupId)
  if (index !== -1) {
    kanbanData.value = kanbanData.value.filter((group) => group.id !== groupId)
  }
  console.log(kanbanData.value)
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="flex justify-around gap-5">
    <KanbanBoardGroup
      v-for="board in kanbanData"
      :key="board.id"
      :title="board.title"
      :id="board.id"
      @delete-group="handleDeleteGroup"
    />
    <CreateKanbanGroup @new-group="handleNewGroup"></CreateKanbanGroup>
  </div>
</template>



"script setup" is syntax sugar, you need to be aware how it translates to actual JS. The use of await results in async component that can only be used with , which you're not using, so the component cannot be rendered. Any wrong types you see in IDE are potentially specific only to to it and aren't related to how code works, this is likely the case here
